# same y axis variable , scatter-plot and long format

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

Let's say two different raters are evaluating behavioral problems. They use the same scale (from 0 to 50) and the child being evaluated is the same for both raters. In social sciences, this method is common and there are some useful statistics, such as correlation coefficient and Intra-Class Correlation.

In addition, one graph that comes to my mind is the scatter-plot, and in the x-axys I'll plot the behavioral problems scores considering the first rater and in the y-axis, I'll do the same for the second rater.

gplot2 creates amazing plots, however, some simple routines and action become really difficult to do.

Please see the code below and the r base plot. I would like to know if ggplot can create this plot as well.

Thanks much
[image: scatter plot r base]

```
   set.seed(123)
ds <- data.frame(behavior_problems = rnorm(100,30,2), evaluator=sample(1:2))
plot(ds$behavior_problems[ds$evaluator == '1'] ,
     y =  ds$behavior_problems[ds$evaluator == '2'])
```

== I had to edit to make clear why a scatter-plot would be informative==

Comment: Why do you think a scatter plot is appropriate here? The observations are not paired in any way. If I were comparing income by sex, I'd be looking at a boxplot or jitter plot, with sex as a factor.

Comment: @neilfws except when men and women are paired via a third variable, maybe marriage ...  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ (sorry, stupid joke)

Comment: The code I create was only to simulate. The real data, the instead of sex is "judge" where people received a score and the scatter-plot is very informative to show the data. @neilfws

Comment: @Luis Then it would be helpful to see the real data. And your current edit is a mix of the old and new questions.

Comment: Sure, @neilfws. The code now makes it clear. It's pretty similar to the original one. Can you please see if everything is ok and clear now? Thanks much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key problem here is the way in which you have set up the data frame. It is not clear that each individual gets a pair of scores, one from each evaluator. So the first thing to do is add an ID for each individual: 50 IDs in your example data.

```
library(tidyverse)
ds %>% 
  mutate(id = rep(1:50, each = 2)
```

Now we can use `tidyr::spread` to create a column for each evaluator. But numbers for column names are not a great idea, so we'll rename them to `e1` and `e2`.

```
ds %>% 
  mutate(id = rep(1:50, each = 2)) %>% 
  spread(evaluator, behavior_problems) %>% 
  rename(e1 = `1`, e2 = `2`)
```

Now we have column names that can be supplied to `ggplot`:

```
ds %>% 
  mutate(id = rep(1:50, each = 2)) %>% 
  spread(evaluator, behavior_problems) %>% 
  rename(e1 = `1`, e2 = `2`) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(e1, e2)) + 
    geom_point()
```

[image]

If this seems like a "long way around", it's because `ggplot2` works better with "long" data (before the spread) than "wide" (after the spread). To illustrate, here's another way to visualize the difference in scores by individual, which I think works quite well:

```
ds %>% 
  mutate(id = rep(1:50, each = 2), 
         evaluator = factor(evaluator)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(id, behavior_problems)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color = evaluator)) + 
    geom_line(aes(group = id))
```

[image]

Comment: This is an amazing solution!! Thanks much!! Now everything is working fine!